# How have Jackson use toString method if object have no public accessors?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am looking for a solution that have Jackson use toString method whenever it can not serialize an object type.

Let me explain more detail.

I have a class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestJackson {
    public String RequestId;
    public AntiSerialize foo;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public LocalDateTime dateRequest;
    public Map<String, Object> headers;

    private static class AntiSerialize {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "AntiSerialize " + ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond();
        }
    }

    public static TestJackson createSample() {
        return new TestJackson(
            "123",
            new TestJackson.AntiSerialize(),
            LocalDateTime.now(),
            Map.of("content", 999,
                "b3", new TestJackson.AntiSerialize(),
                "b4", Arrays.asList(
                    new TestJackson.AntiSerialize(),
                    new TestJackson.AntiSerialize()
                )
            )
        );

    }
}
```

This is to test serialize object

```
var OM = new ObjectMapper()
           .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
try {
    //var f = TestJackson.createSample().foo;
    //out.println(((Object)f).toString());
    var json = OM.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
              .writeValueAsString(TestJackson.createSample());
    out.println(json);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(out);
}
```

It prints

```
{
  "RequestId" : "123",
  "foo" : { },
  "dateRequest" : "2022-08-04 09:04:14",
  "headers" : {
    "b3" : { },
    "b4" : [ { }, { } ],
    "content" : 999
  }
}
```

But I expect:

```
{
  "RequestId" : "123",
  "foo" : "AntiSerialize 1659578741",
  "dateRequest" : "2022-08-04 09:04:14",
  "headers" : {
    "b3" : "AntiSerialize 1659578752",
    "b4" : [ "AntiSerialize 1659578763", "AntiSerialize 1659578774" ],
    "content" : 999
  }
}
```

Assume `TestJackson` is third party class and can't modify.
`AntiSerialize` is also a private nested class.

Comment: static variables are not serialized?